# OCaml Printf.sprintf

Tags: ocaml, printf, type-systems

Why does this behavior occur?

```
# Printf.sprintf ("Foo %d %s") 2 "bar";;
- : string = "Foo 2 bar"

# Printf.sprintf ("Foo %d" ^ " %s") 2 "bar";;
  Printf.sprintf ("Foo %d" ^ " %s") 2 "bar";;
Error: This expression has type string but an expression was expected of type
         ('a -> 'b -> 'c, unit, string) format =
           ('a -> 'b -> 'c, unit, string, string, string, string) format6
```

I would expect that the string concatenation would be evaluated first, so everything will proceed as normal. Does this have to do with the type system trickery that Printf employs?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, it has to do with type system trickery.  If you want to create a format string you need to use the (^^) operator:

```
# Printf.sprintf ("Foo %d" ^^ " %s") 2 "bar";;
- : string = "Foo 2 bar"
```

I'm not deeply schooled in this trickery, but I believe that the compiler is willing to promote a string *constant* to a printf format if the typing context calls for it.  However, the result of `("Foo %d" ^ " %s")` is not a string constant, so it doesn't get promoted.  The (^^) operator creates a typing context where both operands can be promoted if they are string constants.

You can see why it would have to be a string constant: otherwise the associated types (of the values to be printed) can't be determined.

Comment: A fine explanation, thank you. A minor point, I find your formulation "the (^^) operator creates a typing context .." unclear; this operator has no magic inside, it is just typed `... format -> ... format -> ... format`, and type inference does the work of checking that its parameters are of this type, constant strings.

Comment: gasche is right. What needs to be understood is that when you give a string to `Print.*printf` you don't give it a value of type `Pervasives.string` you give it a value of type `Pervasives.format6` (which is not equal to `Pervasives.string`).

Comment: Right, I should just have said that (^^) has the type gasche gives.  There's definitely no magic in that part.  The only magic (as I understand it) is in the promotion of string constants to the appropriate `format` type.

Comment: @gasche: Basically, you can think of a string literal in OCaml as "overloaded"; it can be either a string value or format string value. The type checker determines which one at compile time. Giving a string literal to `printf` directly causes it to be inferred as a format string. Giving it to `^` causes it to be inferred as a string. `^` also returns a string, which is the wrong type for `printf` which is why you get the error.

Answer (score 10):

The problem occurs much more widely than just with the `^` operator. Basically, the OCaml compiler needs to know that your format string is a literal string, and the literal string needs to be known at compile time. Or else, OCaml cannot cast your string at compile time to this `BLAHBLAH format6` type. The `Printf` module works correctly only with format strings that are completely known at compile time, or with format strings that are already cast to the `BLAHBLAH format` type.

Generally you can solve this problem by using the `^^` operator and by explicitly casting all literal strings to the `BLAHBLAH format` type *before* using those strings in your code.

Here is another example:

```
  # Printf.sprintf (if true then "%d" else "%d ") 2;;
  Error: This expression has type string but an expression was expected of type
     ('a -> 'b, unit, string) format =
       ('a -> 'b, unit, string, string, string, string) format6
  (* define a type abbreviation for brevity *)
  # type ('a,'b) fformat = ('a ->'b, unit, string) format;;
  type ('a, 'b) fformat = ('a -> 'b, unit, string) format
  # Printf.sprintf (if true then ("%d":('a,'b)fformat) else ("%d ":('a,'b)fformat)) 2;;
  - : string = "2"
```

The OCaml system cannot recognize that `if ... then "a" else "b"` can be cast to `BLAHBLAH format`. If you cast *each literal string* yourself to `BLAHBLAH format`, then everything works. (Note: it does not work if you try to cast the entire `if/then/else` to `BLAHBLAH format`, since OCaml cannot verify that your string is a literal.)

The origin of the problem is the requirement of type safety: OCaml requires that there is an argument of the correct type for every `%d` and `%s` etc., and guarantees this at *compile time*. You cannot guarantee type safety with `Printf` unless the entire format string is known *at compile time*. Therefore, it is impossible to use `Printf` with a format string computed via a complicated algorithm, e.g., by selecting `%s` and `%d` at random.

When we use `if/then/else` to compute the format string, then OCaml things, oh gee, this is a complicated algorithm, and it is hopeless to verify type safety at compile time. The `^^` operator knows about `BLAHBLAH format` types and produces the correct result when concatenating format strings. But `if/then/else` does not know about `BLAHBLAH format`, and there is no built-in alternative to `if/then/else` (but I guess you could define such a thing youself).