# Converting OCaml strings to format6

Tags: ocaml

The following code does not compile:

```
let x = "hello" in
Printf.printf x
```

The error is:

```
Error: This expression has type string but an expression was expected of type
     ('a, out_channel, unit) format =
       ('a, out_channel, unit, unit, unit, unit) format6
```

1) Can someone give an explanation of the error message?

2) And why would a string cannot be passed to printf ?

Comment: even in C, it's bad practice to pass some variable string as the format to printf

Comment: @newacct: that's not so true, think of a dbg(const char *fmt, ...) function that you would declare yourself.

Comment: @NicolasViennot That would work fine in OCaml though: `let dbg fmt = Printf.printf fmt in dbg "%d %d" 1 2`. The only thing you can't do is to use a format string that you read from a file or as user input.

Comment: see also this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10406493/ocaml-printf-sprintf

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The first argument to printf must be of type `('a, out_channel, unit) format` not string. String literals can be automatically converted to an appropriate format type, but strings in general can't.

The reason for that is that the exact type of a format string depends on the contents of the string. For example the type of the expression `printf "%d-%d"` should be `int -> int -> ()` while the type of `printf "%s"` should be `string -> ()`. Clearly such type checking is impossible when the format string is not known at compile time.

In your case you can just do `printf "%s" x`.

Comment: Or you can just do `print_string x`.

Answer (score 8):

As sepp2k points out, in OCaml `printf` formats have a distinct type, and are not simply strings.  String *literals* are converted automatically to `printf` formats, but `x` is not a string literal.  If you want to give a name to a format, you can convert it explicitly yourself:

```
> let x = format_of_string "hello" in Printf.printf x
hello- : unit = ()
```

You can also cause the implicit conversion by specifying a type for x, but the types of formats are so complicated this is quite painful:

```
# let (x: ('a,'b,'c,'d,'d,'a) format6) = "hello" in Printf.printf x;;
hello- : unit = ()
```

(I personally don't understand the `format6` type.)

Comment: Note that like `printf` `format_of_string` can only be used with string literals, not arbitrary strings. So if you need `x` to be a string, you can't use it to turn `x` into a format just before printing it.

Comment: Absolutely.  As you point out, the string needs to be known at compile time to get type safety.

Comment: I guess that's the double edge sword of a strongly statically typed language :)