# Error around string modification and `printf` in OCaml

Tags: string, ocaml

I want to write a function with input is a List of string, and output is a string.
For example :
List :

```
   3   11 12
    15  13 14 15
```

Output:

```
(assert
     (and  (= (+ x11 x12) 3)  
            (= (+ x13 x14 x15) 15)
))
```

The code I wrote:

```
let print data =
    printf "(assert \n(and ";
    List.iter (fun l ->  
    let str = "(=(+" in 
    str ^ "x" ^(String.concat "x" (List.tl l)) ^ ")" ^ (List.hd l) ^ ")\n";  
    printf str;
    ) data;
    printf "))";
;;
```

But it didn't work. When compiling, it showed error

Please help me to fix it.
Thank you very much

Comment: Please specify what kind of error you get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see three problems.

### Forgot to open `Printf` module

`printf` is used without `open Printf`. Maybe it is done somewhere else, since apparently you did not paste the whole code. Learn to ask good questions.

### Typing glitch of `printf`

`printf str` is not well-typed in OCaml. This is pretty confusing for newcomers. OCaml's `printf` tries to mimic C's printf behaviour and for this purpose its typing is a little strange. To tell it in very short but a bit inaccurately, the rule is:

> `printf` must take its format string argument in constant form. Or you are in trouble.

In your code, `printf "(assert \n(and "` and `printf "))"` is ok since they get string constants, but `printf str` is not. It is a variable.

The easy fix is to use `print_string` instead of `printf`:

```
print_string str
```

should work. `printf` is tricky but I think I should not go further here. If you want to know more, there are several QAs about OCaml's `printf` typing in SO, for example: [OCaml Printf.sprintf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10406493/ocaml-printf-sprintf)

### Wrong "string modification"

Assume that the above typing issue of `printf` is fixed by replacing it by `print_string`.

We still get a warning "Warning 10: this expression should have type unit." around the string concatenation `str ^ "x" ^..` where the questioner tried modifying `str`, but this is wrong.

First, note that this expression does not modify the contents of `str`. It creates a new string by concatenating `str` and other strings. This new string is not used and just discarded in the code, this is why we get the warning. `str` is unchanged and therefore the output would be different from what it would be. Warning 10 is a pretty good indication of this sort of bugs and therefore you should not ignore it.

If you want to print the new string you have to give it to `print_string` (was `printf` in the original code) You should write:

```
let str' = str ^ "x" ^(String.concat "x" (List.tl l)) ^ ")" ^ (List.hd l) ^ ")\n" in
print_string str'
```

or, just

```
print_string (str ^ "x" ^(String.concat "x" (List.tl l)) ^ ")" ^ (List.hd l) ^ ")\n")
```