# printing a float with runtime-selectable precision

Tags: printf, ocaml

This is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10406493/ocaml-printf-sprintf) but not exactly the same.

i naively tried this:

```
let s prec = "%." ^ (string_of_int prec) ^ "f" in
Printf.printf (s 2) 1.23
```

but this is rejected, as well as replacing `^` by `^^`. is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since format string are type-safe they should be known at compile time. You can't take an arbitrary string and use it as a format string. This restriction still allows you to build formats from pieces, you just shouldn't forget to call `format_of_string` function, and make sure that all your formats are static, and resulting formats has the same type.

But, your particular case is already addressed by the formats, so you don't need to do anything fancy here. There is `*` specifier, that does exactly what you want:

```
# printf "%.*f" 10 1.0;;
1.0000000000- : unit = ()
# printf "%.*f" 1 1.0;;
1.0- : unit = ()
```

There is also `Scanf.format_from_string` that allows you to build arbitrary formats from dynamic strings. The following program demonstrates the flexibility of formats in OCaml:

```
let () = 
  print_endline "Floating point format: ";
  let f = match read_line () with
    | "engineering" -> "%e"
    | "regular" -> "%f"
    | "pretty" -> "%g"
    | user -> user in
  let fmt =
    try Scanf.format_from_string f "%f" 
    with exn -> invalid_arg "Unrecognized format" in
  Printf.printf (fmt^^"\n") (4. *. atan 1.)
```

Example:

```
ivg$ ocaml formats.ml 
Floating point format: 
pi = %.16f    
pi = 3.1415926535897931
```

Comment: thanks for the .*  . that's helpful. but in general, it seems to be true that it's impossible to use a non-constant string to generate a format, yes?

Comment: absolutely. But you can still combine constant strings.

Comment: @ivg You can create your format string at run-time in any way you want, you are not limited to “combining constant strings”. The **only** constraint is that the format the string ends up containing matches the type you decided at program-time. So for instance, if `*` did not exist, it would be completely fine to build `"%." ^ (string_of_int width) ^ "f"` and to apply `format_from_string`, claiming it to match `%f`. It will match.

Comment: @gsg, @Pascal, thank you for pointing to `format_from_string`! I've updated the answer.